# Cannot receive DHCP OFFER

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, ifconfig, avahi

Recently my ethernet connection can't work. Seems that I can't receive DHCP OFFER sending by the DHCP server.

My computer : 
OS : Ubuntu 17.10
Kernel : Linux version 4.13.0-38-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-042) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)) #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018

syslog logs :

```
Apr  5 14:52:29 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd-resolved[13849]: Using system hostname 'Thomas-Ubuntu'.
Apr  5 14:52:29 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Apr  5 14:52:29 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting systemd-resolved-update-resolvconf.service...
Apr  5 14:52:29 Thomas-Ubuntu root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/zzz_avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Apr  5 14:52:29 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started systemd-resolved-update-resolvconf.service.
Apr  5 14:52:36 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xac560340)
Apr  5 14:52:53 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xac560340)
Apr  5 14:52:57 Thomas-Ubuntu kernel: [ 4224.078561] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Apr  5 14:53:11 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xac560340)
Apr  5 14:53:30 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xac560340)
Apr  5 14:53:48 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xac560340)
Apr  5 14:53:51 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Apr  5 14:53:51 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[8593]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Apr  5 14:53:51 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Apr  5 14:53:51 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Apr  5 14:53:51 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd-resolved[14055]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd-resolved[14055]: . IN DS 19036 8 2    49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd-resolved[14055]: . IN DS 20326 8 2    e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd-resolved[14055]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa  17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa     23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa     29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan   local private test
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd-resolved[14055]: Using system hostname 'Thomas-Ubuntu'.
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting systemd-resolved-update-resolvconf.service...
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/zzz_avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Apr  5 14:53:52 Thomas-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started systemd-resolved-update-resolvconf.service.
Apr  5 14:54:32 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:54:35 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:54:42 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:54:51 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:55:04 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:55:12 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:55:22 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:55:42 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
Apr  5 14:55:50 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5968]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x60ba1c2f)
```

tcpdump traces :

```
14:55:55.023060 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:d0:55:02:26:db, length 308
14:55:56.180642 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:10:f3:64:03:ee, length 300
14:55:57.876873 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 12:34:56:78:9a:bc, length 300
14:55:57.878446 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 12:34:56:78:9a:bc, length 300
14:56:01.878008 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 12:34:56:78:9a:bc, length 300
14:56:01.890646 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:10:f3:64:03:ee, length 300
14:56:04.618952 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:10:f3:64:03:ee, length 300
14:56:08.607380 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 12:34:56:78:9a:bc, length 300
14:56:09.048996 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b8:6b:23:95:24:7e, length 300
14:56:09.049422 IP 192.168.31.254.67 > 192.168.31.81.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
14:56:09.049450 IP 192.168.31.253.67 > 192.168.31.81.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
14:56:10.090536 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 12:34:56:78:9a:bc, length 300
14:56:11.865126 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:10:f3:64:03:ee, length 300
14:56:14.625331 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:10:f3:64:03:ee, length 300
14:56:17.563527 IP 10.0.0.133.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c0:3f:d5:6c:95:34, length 300
14:56:17.849184 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 40:8d:5c:87:08:00, length 300
14:56:19.640854 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b8:6b:23:95:24:7e, length 300
14:56:19.641390 IP 192.168.31.253.67 > 192.168.31.81.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
14:56:19.641443 IP 192.168.31.254.67 > 192.168.31.81.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

DHCP Server logs :

```
Apr 5 14:55:50  dhcpd       DHCPDISCOVER from b8:6b:23:95:24:7e (Thomas-Ubuntu) via em0
Apr 5 14:55:50  dhcpd       DHCPOFFER on 192.168.31.81 to b8:6b:23:95:24:7e (Thomas-Ubuntu) via em0
Apr 5 14:56:09  dhcpd       DHCPDISCOVER from b8:6b:23:95:24:7e (Thomas-Ubuntu) via em0
Apr 5 14:56:09  dhcpd       DHCPOFFER on 192.168.31.81 to b8:6b:23:95:24:7e (Thomas-Ubuntu) via em0
Apr 5 14:56:19  dhcpd       DHCPDISCOVER from b8:6b:23:95:24:7e (Thomas-Ubuntu) via em0
Apr 5 14:56:19  dhcpd       DHCPOFFER on 192.168.31.81 to b8:6b:23:95:24:7e (Thomas-Ubuntu) via em0
```

Weirdly, tcpdump seems to show that I received an IP adress by the server but nothing happen. Maybe the error on avahi is something to looks at ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

---

EDIT after disable avahi-daemon :

```
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: All rights reserved.
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: 
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:6b:23:95:24:7e
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: Sending on   LPF/eth0/b8:6b:23:95:24:7e
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr  5 15:46:52 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7a4a9f41)
Apr  5 15:46:55 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x7a4a9f41)
Apr  5 15:47:00 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x7a4a9f41)
Apr  5 15:47:13 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x7a4a9f41)
Apr  5 15:47:22 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x7a4a9f41)
Apr  5 15:47:35 Thomas-Ubuntu dhclient[5554]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x7a4a9f41)
```

There is no error anymore but also no IP Adress activated.

---

ADD of ip link output with link on eth1, one USB Ethernet:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:6b:23:95:24:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:3a:64:83:5e:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:eb:97:b6:c1:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:81:62:9e:f9:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br-89a452c50c94: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:3b:ba:d9:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:7f:97:09:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: veth9575945@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-89a452c50c94 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 26:0b:30:dc:2b:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

Comment: Try to disable `avahi` daemon and remove it. It must helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That not seems to solve the issue :

Comment: I've change the description to include new logs.

Comment: Please, try to use `dhclient` command directly: `dhclient <iface_name>`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing already to run my tests.

Comment: Please try this suggestion: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156441&p=7280398#post7280398 .

Comment: I've done the modifications in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf but nothing has changed on the DHCP behaviour. =/

Comment: Maybe it's strange request, but can you try get IP address over DHCP on another machine? I would localise the side of problem.

Comment: That's OK, it's strange problem so strange question don't bother me.

The other PCs on the LAN can get DHCP address without problem. 

Maybe interesting other things : 
With another ethernet port by USB, the problem is exactly the same. 
If I force the address on my ethernet port, I cannot ping the other machines.

Comment: Please add `ip link` output. I should see it.

Comment: It looks like you've got a bridge (presumably to support docker). Does your bridge use eth0 as its route to your LAN? If so you need to stop trying to get an address on eth0 and instead start to request an address from the bridge.

Comment: `eth0` shows `NO CARRIER`.  That's your problem. Plug cable and try again.

Comment: I forget add `ip link set up dev eth0` command if link will not upped automatically.

Comment: No, like I said upside, the eth0 port is down because I try with an other etherport by USB. But the behaviour is the same. 

This is the log line with eth0 plug on : 

    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:6b:23:95:24:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060653/cannot-receive-dhcp-offer-on-ethernet

Comment: did you ever solve this? Also which router are you using? Having the same issue on 2 different mikrotik router based networks.